# Replace NaT values with None and then extracting date from datetime rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
   futuredate
0  NaT
1  2020-07-01 00:00:00
2  NaT
3  2020-07-02 00:00:00
```

My goal is to:

1. convert NaT to None since my result will be converted to json and NaT is not readable
2. extract only the date if the row is not NaT

```
df.futuredate.dt.date
```

But to convert NaT to None I have to convert the column to an object

```
#df["futuredate"] = df["futuredate"].astype(object).where(df["futuredate"], None)
```

which in return the rows that is already a date would have date and time again like this

```
   futuredate
0  None
1  2020-07-01 00:00:00
2  None
3  2020-07-02 00:00:00
```

I would want row 1 and 3 to only have the date but now the column is an object type, how should I approach this?

I tried .replace and .fillna and it doesn't work for NaT rows

Comment: What is reason for `None` ? If generate json like `j = df.to_json()` it working well. - `j = df.to_json()
print (j)
{"futuredate":{"0":null,"1":1593561600000,"2":null,"3":1593648000000}}`

Comment: Maybe is necessary upgrade pandas.

Comment: is pandas 1.0 not assigning NaT to nan datetime rows anymore?

Comment: No, it always assign NaT, but I suggest upgrade if not working correct to_json

Comment: I do use to_json, but after that I have to modify the json using python dictionary. So I'm using json_dumps to covert the dictionary to json

Comment: @cI ask because not sure if possible this replacement, but if generate `dict` then there it is possible.

Comment: hi I solved the problem by treating it as object first and then convert to date for non null rows by using datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(df["futuredate"])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")